# Download a file by clicking on download button using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, download, mechanize

I'd like to download a file, which DOESN'T have a url using mechanize. I tried .read() but it gave me html file, which is obvious. This is the url `http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra?term=SRP000714` where I need to do send to> file> accessionlist and click on create file.

Comment: It *does* have a url. It's just that the download uses a form, which sends POST data. Find out what it sends and replicate that.

Comment: @simonzack Would you mind explaining that a little? I haven't worked with HTML source codes before.

Answer (score 0):

A very, very, very, very lazy way to solve your problem is to use a tool for web scraping.
One which I use when I don't want to think about requests is [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/).
Although it was developed for web application testing, it is suitable enough to do some web scraping.
Take a look at Splinter documentation, everything is very well explained there.

Oh, and it works only with Python 2, which is not so cool.

(certainly there is also a better answer too)